# POSTing JSON to rails with IDs results in Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, activerecord, rails-api

I have a `game` and two `team`s. I want to be able to `POST` something like this to `/games` --

```
{"game":{"home_team":1,"away_team":2,"time":"Wed, 12 Aug 2015 08:08:08 -0500","winner":1,"home_score":2,"away_score":1}}
```

my `game.rb` model looks something like this --

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :home_team_id, :class_name => "Team"
  belongs_to :away_team_id, :class_name => "Team"
  belongs_to :winner_id, :class_name => "Team"
...
end
```

and my `team.rb` model looks like this --

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :home_games, class_name: "Game"
  has_many :away_games, class_name: "Game"
  has_many :winners, class_name: "Game"
...
end
```

The schema for `game` is as follows --

```
  create_table "games", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "home_team_id"
    t.integer  "away_team_id"
    t.datetime "time"
    t.integer  "home_score"
    t.integer  "away_score"
    t.integer  "winner_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "games", ["away_team_id"], name: "index_games_on_away_team", using: :btree
  add_index "games", ["home_team_id"], name: "index_games_on_home_team", using: :btree
  add_index "games", ["winner_id"], name: "index_games_on_winner", using: :btree
```

the error I get is `Team(#70124766940300) expected, got Fixnum(#70124749378140)"`

Comment: Where is your controller code?

Comment: This is happening because the foreign_key and association have the same name.  Can you change your parameter names?  eg - can you make it home_team_id: instead of home_team: ?  Change the foreign key to home_team_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a basic set-up here that is missing.

The schema should not be `"home_team"` and `"away_team"`, but rather `"home_team_id"` and `"away_team_id"`

Also in the Models, there is no need to define `foreign_key: "home_team"` or `foreign_key: "away_team"`. Rails convention (I believe) will assume that `belongs_to :home_team, :class_name => "Team"` has a foreign key of `"home_team_id"`

If you think about it at the Database level (Schema), the Database does not store all the information about the `home_team` in the game table. It only has a `home_game_id` so it references the `home_game`. This way, the Database does not need to duplicate a bunch of data for each association.

There may be other errors in the Controller once this is fixed, but what that error message is telling you is that it gets a Team class rather than a Fixnum, so somewhere it's probably calling `game.home_team` and doing something with it, but you are simply pulling up the home_team ID from your database, not an association.

Comment: This worked, I also had to change my `json` message and the permitted variables.